# How do you change permissions on a registry key in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, windows-registry

My goal is to stop Windows from changing certain keys back to their default settings when the computer reboots.  In answer to a previous question on Super User someone suggested setting a registry key to read-only. But when I look at the permissions there are four (I assume the one `RESTRICTED` is irrelevant so I'll ignore it):

- There's `SYSTEM`
- There's Me (I'm an admin)
- There's `Administrators` (which I assume is the 'default' administrator)

I don't know which one of these to change to make a key read only so that Windows itself can't alter it unless I change its permissions back. Further, I don't seem to be *able* to change the permissions on anything but the `RESTRICTED` user.

If it matters the specific keys I want to set to be unchangeable by Windows are:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\MouseSensitivity`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\SwapMouseButtons`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make changes to permissions, you need to uncheck the **Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent** checkbox:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
Do you know which of the mentioned users I make the change to?

Comment: I'd change them all if you want it to be read-only (though you _could_ experiment). Make sure that Read access is still available for all.